# How to relocate the labels on a zoomable map?

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on a map that is created by D3.js. I figured out how to zoom in the map and add labels by following [Mike Bostock's tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/). However, after I zoomed in the map, I don't know how to recalculate the coordinates of the labels.

I don't really understand how `projection(data.geometry.coordinates)` works. It seems `projection()` will recreate a pair of new coordinates based on the current svg, and somehow automatically place the labels for you. Thus, I tried to run `projection()` again in the `clicked()` function, but it doesn't work.

Here is the [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/gFRul4PKGrRVIxyCILRK?p=preview) that I'm working on, and I'm using d3 version 4, instead of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add your towns to the `g` selection (instead of the `svg` selection), then it should work fine, as the zoom applies to that selection.

```
var selection = g
        .selectAll("g.classTown")
        .data(towns);
```

updated code: http://plnkr.co/edit/xJvh6LVweZqQUs7GFFH7?p=preview

Comment: Does this mean `projection()` will automatically place the labels after zoomed in based on the current element's scale, in this case `g`?

Comment: No, the projection() returns the [x,y] coordinates in the SVG space. Zoom transforms that space, adjusting your view of everything that it contains.